# Bitbucket pull requests automatically merging in code?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, pull-request

I'm just playing around with the bitbucket/mercurial pull requests feature, and either something is behaving strangely, or I'm doing something profoundly stupid.

I (theukdave) am the owner of a repository 'RepoA' which was created under a 'team' (which I gather bitbucket doesn't really have anymore).  Let's say this lives at bitbucket.org/team1/RepoA

So I created a fork of that repository under my own username and called it RepoB.  So now there's a fork that lives at bitbucket.org/theukdave/RepoB

I then create a test commit on a branch off our main development branch 'develop', and then merged that new branch back into develop.  I pushed up to bitbucket.org/theukdave/RepoB, and then created a pull request from 'theukdave/RepoB develop' to 'team1/RepoA develop', I add a title and description and NO reviewers (since I'm just testing right now) and click the 'create pull request' button.

A few moments later, the test commit and merge from RepoB is showing up in my RepoA.  The pull request is there, I can see it, I have not yet approved it, but the commit and merge and available to all users of RepoA.  Even if I decline the pull request, the test commits are still in RepoA.

Is this because I'm the owner of RepoA, and so my pull requests are automatically merged in? Is it because I added no reviewers? A combo of both?  Or am I missing something here ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some really specific configuration which are near impossible to reproduce in order to test / help the OP

Comment: I didn't think it was *that* configuration specific.  I have 2 repos (one is a fork of the other), and I'm trying to use commit requests from the fork to the original.  Commits are automatically appearing in the original repo before being approved.

Answer (score 0):

First of all really interesting. You can resolve this situation using this steps.

To disable automatic branch merging for all repositories in a project (requires project **admin permission**):

Go to **Project settings >** Branching model.
Select **Disable automatic merging**, then click Save.

I hope useful for you.